# Why AWS Lambda keeps timing out when using Knex.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, knex.js

I have a AWS Lambda function that connects to a RDS instance using the Knex.js NPM module. After I get the data from the DB, and call the `callback()` function, the AWS Lambda won’t exit, won’t send back a response and will time out.

If I `console.log()` the result from the DB I see the data, meaning the retrieval of the information from the DB was successful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that by default AWS Lambda will wait for the event loop to be empty before terminating the execution of the function. This means that even if you call the `callback()` function, AWS Lambda won't quit. To change this behavior you need to set `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` to `false`. This tells AWS Lambda to quit even when the event loop is not empty, which in this case it is our DB connection.

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

Comment: Is there anything else to this? I have this set on a migration run but no matter what I try (knex.destroy(), process.exit(0) inside the promise.then()), the lambda always runs to the limit of whatever timeout value is set in the cloudformation template.

Comment: Nope this is it. But this was a solution for 2018 years ago. Maybe now with NodeJS 12, they did change something. Plus now you have Database Proxy, you should just use that: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/